# Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy method copies row beyond the range specified

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub that does "auto-filtering" in "Sheet1" and I only wanted to copy the filtered results and paste it on a sheet named "RESULTS" so I used Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy. My problem is that, when the filter has no results, it still copies the header of the filtered table, which is not supposed to happen because the range specified in "rangestring" starts from A16 and the header is in row 15. Any fix for this one? thanks.

```
Sub selectVisibleRange()

    Dim DbExtract, DuplicateRecords As Worksheet
    Dim lastrowTable, lastrowResults As Long
    Dim rangestring As String
    
    Set DbExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set DuplicateRecords = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RESULTS")
    
    'get last row for table to be filtered
    lastrowTable = DbExtract.Cells(DbExtract.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    rangestring = "A16:V" & lastrowTable
    
    'check whether there are results in the auto_filter, copy rows that are results
    If DbExtract.Range(rangestring).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 0 Then
        'get latest update/last row in RESULTS sheet
        lastrowResults = DuplicateRecords.Cells(DuplicateRecords.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        
        'copy row for the PN used for filter
        DbExtract.Range("A6:V6").Copy
        DuplicateRecords.Cells(lastrowResults + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        'get latest update/last row in RESULTS sheet for the PN results
        lastrowResults = DuplicateRecords.Cells(DuplicateRecords.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        
        'copy PN filtered resutls
        DbExtract.Range(rangestring).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        DuplicateRecords.Cells(lastrowResults + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    
    Set DbExtract = Nothing
    Set DuplicateRecords = Nothing

End Sub
```

I added an "If" statement to check whether it has filtered results. I guess the IF statement is not working as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the results of auto_filter is nothing (all rows are hidden), then the value of `lastrowTable` equals *15* (the header row). That's the reason why the header is copied to the destination.

`rangestring` is `"A16:V15"`.

`DbExtract.Range(rangestring).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`

equals

`DbExtract.Range("A15:V15").Copy    ' Row 16 is hidden`

You can check the auto-filter result as below.

```
    lastrowTable = DbExtract.Cells(DbExtract.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    If lastrowTable > 15 Then
        rangestring = "A16:V" & lastrowTable
        ' your code
    End If
```

Comment: Changed my If-statement to the one you wrote and it worked. Headers aren't being copied anymore.